# Associate users with Custom Post Type and list associated users

Tags: custom-post-types

I have created a Custom Post Type called **Program**

I want logged in users to get associated with a program:

1. User goes to **Program** page
2. User clicks on **Register** button
3. User fills details in the form and pushes **Submit** button.

Afterwards I should be able to create a report which lists:

1. All the users who are associated with any Program
2. List of users who are associated with a selected program & role

How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom taxonomy:

```
add_action( 'init', function(){
    register_taxonomy( 'program', 'your_post_type', array() );
});
```

To get users associated with a program, get all posts that have your desired program term:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'your_post_type',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'program',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => 'your_program_name',
        ),
    ),
) );
```

Now get all the result posts authors and that would give you the users associated to that specific program.

```
$posts = $query->posts;

foreach($posts as $post) {
    $author = $post->post_author;
}
```

Comment: As far as my understanding, custom taxonomy are used for categorizes the custom post type i.e.Program but my requirement is when a logged-in user click on register program link/button of a post (CPT) i.e. Program, User Detail is collected in Database which we retrieve to get the total count of user registered for the selected program.

Comment: The user will create one of your CPT which will make him the author. That's already a link you can use without further complicating things, if you want to add context to that link between a CPT 'program' and it's author, then you use a taxonomy term, ex: 'Chrome'.